# Trim a string while it is being copied to new cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently using this to get the unique values from a column.  I am trying to modify that unique value and trim out characters before it pastes to the destination.

```
Dim Cl As Range

    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        For Each Cl In wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Range("X9", Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If Not .exists(Cl.Value) Then
            .Add Cl.Value, Nothing
            'Cl.Value = Left(Cl, Len(Cl) - 5)
            End If
        Next Cl
        wbTo.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F12").Resize(.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.keys)
    End With
```

I am not sure where or how to implement the line: `Cl.Value = Left(Cl, Len(Cl) - 7)` or if this is even the best route.

The source data is '36 Months' and I am trying to trim out anything except the numbers themselves, resulting in just '36' being paste into my field.  All of the values will be in an 'XX Months' format, and should always be 2 digits.

EDIT:  I also just noticed that the code above pastes into cell F13 instead of F12 - Any ideas why it is adding a row before being paste?  I suspect the 'transpose' aspect, but can't see any other reason.

Comment: If they're all 2 digit numbers then I don't think there'd be any problem just saying `Cl.Value = Left$(Cl.Value, 2)`. I'd say it mostly depends on what different variations there are in your data

Comment: This all depends on what other values might be in the range.  You need detail this more for us.  Do all of the values follow a specific format(s)?  If so, what are they?

Comment: I've updated my post - but yes, all the months fields will be in a 'XX Months' format, and should always be a 2 digit month amount, followed by a space and the word Months

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 - Thank you!  This worked when I found the right place to put it.  (Thats what she said!)

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
For Each Cl In wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Range("X9", Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            v = Left(Cl, Len(Cl) - 5)
            If Not .exists(v) Then
                .Add v, Nothing
            End If
Next Cl
```

Comment: Oh, that's probably what the OP trying to do. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Am getting an Invalid Procedure call or argument error with  `v = Left(Cl, Len(Cl) - 5)`  even after assigning it to a Dim.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution for those with the same issue, wanted to post it here.

```
Dim Cl As Range
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each Cl In wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Range("X9", Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        Cl.Value = Left$(Cl.Value, 2)  '<--- Magic spot

        If Not .exists(Cl.Value) Then
        .Add Cl.Value, Nothing
        End If
    Next Cl
    wbTo.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D11").Resize(.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.keys)
End With
```

This also seemed to work for me:

```
           Cla.Value = Replace(Cla.Value, " Months", "")
```